# Has anyone come accross the RPC server not available issue when sending email on Outlook with Blue Prism?

Tags: outlook, rpc, rpa, blueprism

When I try to send an email via Outlook with Blue Prism, at random moments, it will give me an error on the RPC server (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA). Would anyone know the problem for this issue? If yes, how do you fix it?

Comment: I have the same issue and I get this error randomly. I don't have a solution to the problem  yet :(

Answer (score 0):

This means you have disconnected your Outlook/similar-office-product-instance and you are trying to execute an action again with the instance but it's not connected to anything. Trying exiting when you get this error or killing outlook task and doing the task again with creating a new instance etc and you should be good to go from there.